# Running a QGIS processing model using qgis_process

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I am trying to run a QGIS processing model (.model3) standalone using qgis_process. It works when running single algorithms, but I am having trouble running a model file. How would a correct call look? Mine looks like this:

```
qgis_process run C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\models\Dissolve_SHP.model3 --INPUT="H:\path\an_riks.shp" --OUTPUT="C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\an_riks_dissolved.shp"
```

The response I get is:

ERROR: The following mandatory parameters were not specified

```
    native:dissolve_1:OUTPUT:       OUTPUT
```

How are these parameters specified for a model? I have been unable to find any documentation on this, see for example https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/200. It looks fairly easy at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/140, but I must be missing something.

Magnus